# Ориентированный граф. Реализация алгоритма Дейкстры

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Как реализовать данный алгоритм, если у меня граф представлен в виде списка рёбер. C матрицей смежности всё понятно, а вот со списком...
P.S Или может кто подскажет как перейти от списка рёбер к матрице смежности

Answer (score 3):

Создай пустую матрицу смежности и заполняй необходимые значения по списку ребер.
Элемент из списка ребер - это пара чисел, каждая из которых представляет номер вершины.
Стало быть, чтобы заполнить матрицу смежности тебе просто нужно пробежаться по всем ребрам из списка.   
Допустим у тебя есть ребро (1,2). Стало быть элемент матрицы, стоящий в 1 строке и во 2 столбце равен единице. И так, пробегая весь список, заполнишь матрицу смежности.

Comment: @barselona1002, структуру элемента списка ребер приведите (или сами на нее внимательно посмотрите).

Comment: @avp, т.е третий столбец списка рёбер - расстояние

Comment: Не знаю как у тебя хранится список ребер, но, допустим, хранится в txt. Каждая строчка - ребро. Тогда просто считываешь построчно, парсишь строку и дальше так:        
первый элемент это строка матрицы, второй - столбец, третий - значение.

Comment: @barselona, изучите указатели (ссылки) и списочные структуры данных,
думаю это будет в самый раз для представления графа и  реализации алгоритма Дейкстры.